# Responsive 4 column image grid for portfolio

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want to make a portfolio using only html, css and js. The number of columns should be 4 and should be responsive when resized. I found this code which is kind of perfect but the problem is it contains more then 4 columns- http://codepen.io/bradfrost/pen/xkcBn.

Is there a way to make it into just 4 columns..thanks

Here's the CSS

```
.g {
        padding: 0.25em;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .g li {
            float: left;
            width: 50%;
            padding: 0.25em;
        }
        .g img {
            display: block;
        }
        .g li:nth-child(odd) {
            clear: left;
        }

        @media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
            .g li {
                width: 33.3333333333333333%; 
            }
            .g li:nth-child(3n+1) {
                clear: left;
            }
            .g li:nth-child(odd) {
                clear: none;
            }
        }
        @media screen and (min-width: 55em) {
            .g li {
                width: 25%; 
            }
            .g li:nth-child(4n+1) {
                clear: left;
            }
            .g li:nth-child(3n+1) {
                clear: none;
            }
        }
        @media screen and (min-width: 72em) {
            .g li {
                width: 20%; 
            }
            .g li:nth-child(5n+1) {
                clear: left;
            }
            .g li:nth-child(4n+1) {
                clear: none;
            }
        }
        @media screen and (min-width: 90em) {
            .g li {
                width: 16.666666666%; 
            }
            .g li:nth-child(6n+1) {
                clear: left;
            }
            .g li:nth-child(5n+1) {
                clear: none;
            }
        }
```

Comment: As the screen becomes bigger more columns are added.

Comment: Use Foundation or Twitter Bootstrap... there are so many template available already!!!

Comment: here is one of the example from Foundation > http://foundation.zurb.com/templates/workspace.html

Comment: is this what you are looking for???

Comment: thanks..i used the bootstrap template. but i was hoping to find a solution with just css and html

Answer (score -1):

Here is my lazy answer to your laziness. 
http://jsfiddle.net/z38g0Le5/

```
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>

<style>
    .box {width:25%; display:inline-block;}
</style>
```

seriously there are so many resource out there...